# Why does my android device not connect to charles proxy but works when I connect to Fiddler proxy?

Tags: android, proxy, charles-proxy

When I have Fiddler up and running i can connect my android phone to it. I should be able to connect to Charles (once I have closed Fiddler) using the same settings (my computer IP and port 8888).

However, when trying to connect to Charles my phone browser times out and says check internet connection.

navigating to localhost:8888 shows charles and my computer browser connects successfully.

i also dont get the prompt on Charles when i try and connect using the phone.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely didn't install the Charles certificate on the Android device.

Go to 'chls.pro/ssl' on your Android device, and install the certificate that it shows you.

Comment: If I navigate to the url using fiddler it doesnt install?  Do I need to be using Charles access the internet through proxy to install it?

Comment: Yes, you need to be connected to Charles, otherwise it doesn't install.